# JSF Status bar / connection status information

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I would like to implement a kind of information for my users about the progress status. I have found several components like:

[Richfaces status](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/status.jsf?c=status&tab=usage) or [IceFaces onnection Status](http://component-showcase.icefaces.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface)

So, I would like to add something like that to my page especially for ajax requests. What's the easiest way to implement it? I would not like to use one of those components, rather programming my own one but I can't imagine how and how much effort it takes :-)

I am thankfull for ideas...

Comment: PrimeFaces has by the way also a [`p:ajaxStatus`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprAjaxStatus.jsf).

Comment: Updated link for [<p:ajaxStatus >](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxStatusHome.jsf)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard JSF implementation doesn't provide a ready-to-use component for this. The [JSF 2.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr314/index.html) however outlines the following in chapter 13.3.5.2:

> #### 13.3.5.2 Monitoring Events For All Ajax Requests
>
> The JavaScript API provides the `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent` function that can be used to register a JavaScript function
>   that will be notified when any Ajax request/response event occurs. Refer to Section 14.4 “Registering Callback
>   Functions” for more details. The `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent` function accepts a JavaScript function argument that will be
>   notified when events occur during any Ajax request/response event cycle. The implementation must
>   ensure the JavaScript function that is registered must be called in accordance with the events outlined in
>   Section TABLE 14-3 “Events”.

You can find [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/05/15/jsf-2-ajax-events-and-errors) a blog of one of the Mojarra developers which contains basic examples. Here's an extract of relevance:

> ```
> <h3> Status:</h3>
> <textarea id="statusArea" cols="40" rows="10" readonly="readonly" />
> ```
>
> A simple textarea, not even hooked
>   into the backend server data model.
>
> Then in our javascript (for the demo,
>   in a separately loaded file, though it
>   could just as easily be in page) we
>   have:
>
> ```
> var statusUpdate = function statusUpdate(data) {
>     var statusArea = document.getElementById("statusArea");
>     var text = statusArea.value;
>     text = text + "Name: "+data.source.id;
>     if (data.type === "event") {
>         text = text +" Event: "+data.name+"\n";
>     } else {  // otherwise, it's an error
>         text = text + " Error: "+data.name+"\n";
>     }
>     statusArea.value = text;
> };
>
> // Setup the statusUpdate function to hear all events on the page
> jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(statusUpdate);
> jsf.ajax.addOnError(statusUpdate);
> ```