# p:ajaxStatus for f:ajax requests

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to use Primefaces p:ajaxStatus for normal f:ajax requests. Or maybe there's an opensource component for status icons for normal JSF ajax requests that i can use and style it the same way as Primefaces one?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556676/jsf-status-bar-connection-status-information/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043840/jsf-2-how-show-different-ajax-status-in-same-input/

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need a component. A simple piece of Javascript will do (what follows is a proof-of-concept, no ajax error handling, supports only one ajax request at a time, no special js libraries - fixes are left as an exercise for the reader):

```
<img id='busy' src='busy.png' style='display: none'>
<img id='notbusy' src='notbusy.png'>
<script>
  var evil_global_busy = document.getElementById('busy')
  var evil_global_notbusy = document.getElementById('notbusy')
  jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(e){
     if (e.status == "begin") {
        evil_global_busy.style.display = '';
        evil_global_notbusy.style.display = 'none';
     }
     if (e.status == "success") {
        evil_global_busy.style.display = 'none';
        evil_global_notbusy.style.display = '';
     }
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on PrimeFace,  covers all ajax request of the site, including the attribute 'update'

```
<p:ajaxStatus>
   <f:facet name="start">
       <h:graphicImage library="image" name="loading.gif" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="error">
       <h:outputText value="Error. " />
    </f:facet>
       <f:facet name="complete">
    <h:outputText value="" />
    </f:facet>
 </p:ajaxStatus>
```